# Ubuntu Bionic Server edition + Netplan: Not getting static IP on a ethernet connection

Tags: netplan

**Problem:** I cannot get a static IP on the ethernet port.

**Aim:** Trying to setup a static IP on the Realtek built-in ethernet (enp3s0) port so I can connect the server to my desktop via a crossover cable. At the moment, there is no cable connected between the 2.

**Setup:** Ubuntu Bionic server edition with Intel WiFi card and a Reaktek ethernet port. During installation, I had to connect the ethernet port to my modem/router as the Ubuntu installer cannot recognize my WiFi card.

---

**Things I've tried:**

1. I disabled my WiFi card  and then I've tried using just "dchp4: true" and then connected a cable from the port to my modem/router. No issues getting an IP and pinging a site.
2. I've tried with and without "renderer: networkd", no difference.
3. I've tried with and without "dhcp4" false", no difference.
4. I've tried with and without gateway4, no difference.
5. I've tried with and without nameservers, no difference.
6. sudo netplan --debug apply doesn't show any errors
7. I looked at the generated config inside /run/systemd/network (included below) and looks ok.
8. Debugged systemd-networkd as suggested by this page (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSystemd) and I can see this line: "enp3s0: Link is not managed by us". That doesn't seemed right as I don't have anything else managing my interfaces and as I said in no.1, using DHCP worked.

**Here's my current config:**

---

```
>cat /etc/netplan/01-wireless.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "insert-access-point-here":
          password: "insert-password-here"

>cat /etc/netplan/02-ethernet.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [192.168.2.1/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.2.254


>cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-wlp2s0.network 
[Match]
Name=wlp2s0
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
[DHCP]
UseMTU=true
RouteMetric=600

>cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp3s0.network 
[Match]
Name=enp3s0
[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.168.2.1/24
Gateway=192.168.2.254
```

---

**Results of netplan --debug apply**

```
sudo netplan --debug apply                      
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.754: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-wireless.yaml..
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: starting new processing pass
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: wlp2s0: adding wifi AP 'myhotspot'
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: Processing input file /etc/netplan/02-ethernet.yaml..
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: starting new processing pass
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: wlp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: Generating output files..
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: wlp2s0: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlp2s0.conf
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/netplan-wpa@wlp2s0.service
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: NetworkManager: definition wlp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:13784): DEBUG: 03:16:37.755: NetworkManager: definition enp3s0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration exists, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:wlp2s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:enp3s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.2.1/24
      gateway4: 192.168.2.254
  vlans: {}
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      access-points:
        insert-access-point-here:
          password: insert-password-here
      dhcp4: true

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:device wlp2s0 operstate is up, not changing
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp3s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for wlp2s0
```

**Results of systemd networkd debugging:**

---

```
>sudo SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Failed to read $container of PID 1, ignoring: Permission denied
Found container virtualization none.
Bus n/a: changing state UNSET → OPENING
Bus n/a: changing state OPENING → AUTHENTICATING
Failed to open configuration file '/etc/systemd/networkd.conf': No such file or directory
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/run/systemd/network' changed
Ignoring /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp3s0.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .netdev.
Ignoring /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-wlp2s0.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .netdev.
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link, because it's not a regular file with suffix .netdev.
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/80-container-ve.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .netdev.
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/80-container-vz.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .netdev.
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .netdev.
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link, because it's not a regular file with suffix .network.
wlp2s0: Flags change: +UP +LOWER_UP +RUNNING +MULTICAST +BROADCAST
wlp2s0: Link 3 added
wlp2s0: udev initialized link
wlp2s0: Saved original MTU: 1500
enp3s0: Flags change: +UP +MULTICAST +BROADCAST
enp3s0: Link 2 added
enp3s0: udev initialized link
enp3s0: Saved original MTU: 1500
lo: Flags change: +LOOPBACK +UP +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
lo: Link 1 added
lo: udev initialized link
lo: Saved original MTU: 0
wlp2s0: Adding address: fe80::3613:e8ff:fe41:a078/64 (valid forever)
wlp2s0: Gained IPv6LL
lo: Adding address: ::1/128 (valid forever)
wlp2s0: Adding address: 192.168.1.2/24 (valid forever)
lo: Adding address: 127.0.0.1/8 (valid forever)
rtnl: received address with invalid family 129, ignoring
Enumeration completed
Bus n/a: changing state AUTHENTICATING → HELLO
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=Hello cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=RequestName cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=su error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=AddMatch cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=4 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=5 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_31 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=7 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=8 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=9 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
wlp2s0: Link state is up-to-date
wlp2s0: found matching network '/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-wlp2s0.network'
enp3s0: Link is not managed by us
lo: Link is not managed by us
LLDP: Started LLDP client
wlp2s0: Started LLDP.
wlp2s0: Acquiring DHCPv4 lease
DHCP CLIENT (0x8f3ad0c0): STARTED on ifindex 3
wlp2s0: Discovering IPv6 routers
NDISC: Started IPv6 Router Solicitation client
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=10 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=11 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=12 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 3s
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.12 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Bus n/a: changing state HELLO → RUNNING
DHCP CLIENT (0x8f3ad0c0): DISCOVER
Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus.Local destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/DBus/Local interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Local member=Connected cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.12 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.12 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.12 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4 reply_cookie=2 signature=u error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Successfully acquired requested service name.
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.12 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=5 reply_cookie=3 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Match type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.login1',path='/org/freedesktop/login1',interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',member='PrepareForSleep' successfully installed.
enp3s0: Link state is up-to-date
enp3s0: found matching network '/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp3s0.network'
lo: Link is not managed by us
wlp2s0: Link does not request DHCPv6 prefix delegation
LLDP: Started LLDP client
enp3s0: Started LLDP.
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=13 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
lo: Link state is up-to-date
No virtualization found in DMI
No virtualization found in CPUID
Virtualization XEN not found, /proc/xen does not exist
This platform does not support /proc/device-tree
No virtualization found in /proc/cpuinfo.
This platform does not support /proc/sysinfo
Found VM virtualization none
lo: Unmanaged
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_31 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=14 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
wlp2s0: Removing address: 192.168.1.2/24 (valid forever)
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=15 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=16 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
DHCP CLIENT (0x8f3ad0c0): OFFER
DHCP CLIENT (0x8f3ad0c0): REQUEST (requesting)
DHCP CLIENT (0x8f3ad0c0): ACK
wlp2s0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.1.2/24 via 192.168.1.1
wlp2s0: Updating address: 192.168.1.2/24 (valid forever)
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=17 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=18 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
wlp2s0: DHCP error: could not get routes: No data available
wlp2s0: Configured
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=19 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 7s
NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 14s
NDISC: No RA received before link confirmation timeout
NDISC: Invoking callback for 't'.
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Do you have any tabs in your .yaml files? In your ethernet .yaml, try changing `dhcp6: yes` to no or false, and retry. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Hello. I checked my YAML file and only spaces were used. I also don't have any files in /etc/network/interfaces. As a test, I created a new virtual box and I have no issues assigning a static IP there.

Comment: Everything looks ok from here. Did you reboot the server after the netplan apply? I've seen netplan wonky that way, and I always recommend the reboot. Report back.